# How can I calculate the F1 score using Mask RCNN?

Tags: python, cnn, object-detection, faster-rcnn, f1score

I customized the "https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN.git" repository to train with my own data set, for object detection, ignoring the mask segmentation part. Now I am evaluating my results, I can calculate the MAP, but I cannot calculate the F1 score.

I have this function: compute_ap, from "https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/mrcnn/utils.py" which returns the "mAP, details, memories, overlays" for each image. The point is, I cannot apply the F1 score formula, because the variables "precision" and "recalls" are lists.

How can I calculate the F1 score using Mask RCNN?

I am using the standard formula to calculate the f1-score, as shown in the image, is this the correct formula to calculate f1-score for object detection models?
[image: Image formula f1-score]

Here is my code:

```
def compute_ap(gt_boxes, gt_class_ids, gt_masks,
               pred_boxes, pred_class_ids, pred_scores, pred_masks,
               iou_threshold=0.5):

    # Get matches and overlaps
    gt_match, pred_match, overlaps = compute_matches(
        gt_boxes, gt_class_ids, gt_masks,
        pred_boxes, pred_class_ids, pred_scores, pred_masks,
        iou_threshold)

    # Compute precision and recall at each prediction box step
    precisions = np.cumsum(pred_match > -1) / (np.arange(len(pred_match)) + 1)
    recalls = np.cumsum(pred_match > -1).astype(np.float32) / len(gt_match)

    # Pad with start and end values to simplify the math
    precisions = np.concatenate([[0], precisions, [0]])
    recalls = np.concatenate([[0], recalls, [1]])

    # Ensure precision values decrease but don't increase. This way, the
    # precision value at each recall threshold is the maximum it can be
    # for all following recall thresholds, as specified by the VOC paper.
    for i in range(len(precisions) - 2, -1, -1):
        precisions[i] = np.maximum(precisions[i], precisions[i + 1])

    # Compute mean AP over recall range
    indices = np.where(recalls[:-1] != recalls[1:])[0] + 1
    mAP = np.sum((recalls[indices] - recalls[indices - 1]) *
                 precisions[indices])

    return mAP, precisions, recalls, overlaps
```